# How to Optimize a Mysql table of 1Gb size 250k+ rows for better performance

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

Now my table is in MYISAM because I use FULL TEXT SEARCH.

I have a column in this table thats has text more like a blog post. That column contributes max. to  this table's size. This column is not even used in FULL TEXT SEARCH.

About 20-50 rows are inserted in this table every 6 hours. So, most of the time its just reading data from it.

Should I switch to Innodb? Or create another table in Innodb with just 2 columns as massive column and rel. id. Or I should write this column into txt files and access those when needed.

I am totally confused and most of the articles, questions didn't help me much.

Any suggestions on what should I do to improve its performance?

Comment: When are you experiencing issues with performance? While doing what?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running, as they recently added FullText support for innodb.

Comment: As @BenGriffiths said, InnoDB added FT indexing recently and it's much more advanced engine, 1GB of data and several hundreds of megabytes of indexes should easily fit its cache.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given enough information to determine any cost versus benefit ratios, or even if the current performance might be reasonable.  You can optimize any system indefinitely, but you need to keep in mind **Is it now good enough?**

The surest answer is to implement *all* reorganizations and time them.  Since there seems to be only one table in question, it should not take more than a few hours of engineering effort, plus whatever time it takes for the imports to run.